# Any existing tool for JavaScript execution context Visualizations?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering whether there is already exists such tool doing:

1. parse JS code (not expecting big block)
2. visualize execution context / scope chain, and even prototype chain.

The motivation is simply because JS execution context, scope chain is usually confusing, especially for non-advanced guys. Visualization could make thing to be better understood.

Otherwise, could you have some suggestions regarding building up from scratch.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So you need a debugger?  Tried Venkman?

Comment: Not just a debugger but want visualize execution context so that people can get better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I recently saw a video on youtube [JS-Visualizer sneak peek demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPyNIWm47-4). However I could not find any online link or github repo to experiment with it. I have left a youtube comment for the author to provide some link to access the tool. May be more feedback and comments to the author will encourage him to do so.

Comment: looks quite cool and pretty much what I like. Let's see if the author reply anything. Thanks.

Comment: Hey guys, I was part of the team that originally built this tool. We did it as a group project while we were students at [Hack Reactor](http://www.hackreactor.com/). We transferred ownership of the project to some staff at Hack Reactor when we graduated. The staff was planning to polish it up and use it as part of the program potentially. From what I've heard, it has been put on the back burner for the moment.